How to add CI below the mean row using gtsummary?
I can use the tbl_summary to generate the summary table, including the mean (sd), median (IQR), and range, however I would like to add a row under the mean row to include the confidence interval for the mean. but with the code below, I can only get the CI as additional columns. I am hoping if anyone can help me.
data |>
  tbl_summary(by=Cohort,
              type = all_continuous() ~ 'continuous2',
              include = c(`Total value 1`),
              statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})", "{median} ({p25}, {p75})", "{min},{max}"),
  ) |>
  add_ci() |>
  add_overall(last=TRUE) |>
  bold_labels() |>
  add_stat_label(label = all_continuous() ~ c("Mean (SD)", "Median (IQR)", "Min, Max")) |>
  as_gt()



See below to two approaches to get the 95%CI for mean in your table. Happy programming!
library(gtsummary)

# Method 1: Define fns for LB and UB ------------

conf.low <- function(x) t.test(x)$conf.int[1]
conf.high <- function(x) t.test(x)$conf.int[2]

trial |> 
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt, 
    include = age,
    missing = "no",
    type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})", "{conf.low}, {conf.high}", "{median} ({p25}, {p75})", "{min}, {max}")
  ) |> 
  add_stat_label(label = all_continuous() ~ c("Mean (SD)", "95% CI", "Median (IQR)", "Min, Max")) |> 
  bold_labels() |> 
  as_kable()




Characteristic
Drug A N = 98
Drug B N = 102




Age




Mean (SD)
47 (15)
47 (14)


95% CI
44, 50
45, 50


Median (IQR)
46 (37, 60)
48 (39, 56)


Min, Max
6, 78
9, 83





# Method 2: Use ARD data structure --------------
library(cards)

trial |> 
  # first create ARD data frame of results
  ard_stack(
    .by = trt, 
    ard_continuous(
      variables = age, 
      statistic = ~ continuous_summary_fns(other_stats = list(ttest = \(x) t.test(x) |> broom::tidy()))
    ),
    .attributes = TRUE, 
    .missing = TRUE
  ) |> 
  # build table with ARD
  tbl_ard_summary(
    by = trt,
    type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})", "{conf.low}, {conf.high}", "{median} ({p25}, {p75})", "{min}, {max}")
  ) |> 
  add_stat_label(label = all_continuous() ~ c("Mean (SD)", "95% CI", "Median (IQR)", "Min, Max")) |> 
  bold_labels() |> 
  as_kable()




Characteristic
Drug A
Drug B




Age




Mean (SD)
47.0 (14.7)
47.4 (14.0)


95% CI
43.9, 50.1
44.6, 50.3


Median (IQR)
46.0 (37.0, 60.0)
48.0 (39.0, 56.0)


Min, Max
6.0, 78.0
9.0, 83.0



Created on 2024-10-23 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you, Daniel! this is super helpful!
